# Swift Array will not populate with JSON Data

Tags: arrays, json, swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

The issue I am facing is that i am unable to populate the empty array with the JSON Data and can not find a similar problem asked on StackOverflow.

Within the function itself I can get the empty array and populate the array within the function. Then call a print function within the downloadRestaurantDetails function to see the information i had parsed.

But I am unable to populate the original empty array that is outside of the function so that I can get the populated array and use it in a different function.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var placeIDArray = [String]()
var placeID: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadRestaurantDetails { () -> () in

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func downloadRestaurantDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    //url is acquired through a file created for global variables
    Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if let value  = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)

            //Acquire All place_id of restaurants
            if let results = json["results"].array {
                for result in results {
                    if let allPlace_ID = result["place_id"].string {
                        //Add All place_id's into an array
                        self.placeIDArray.append(allPlace_ID)
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    // i call this method to check and see if there is anything placed in the array outside of the downloadRestaurantDetails method.

    func check() {
    if self.placeIDArray.count > 1 {
        print(self.placeIDArray)

    } else {
        print(self.placeIDArray.count)
    }
}
```

To conclude, the issue I would like to solve,

- I would like to parse the place_id and place the resulting strings in the
  placeIDArray. I am able to parse the data and store the values inside of the placeIDArray within the function. I am not able to store the parsed data in the empty array out of the function. I had thought that by using self.placeIDArray the parsed data would be assigned to the array. but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: still stumped on this, anybody have an idea?

Comment: Where are you attempting to access the value of `placeIDArray` when you  check to see if the data is assigned to it?

Comment: i created a function to check to see if i can access the data in the array and print it to the debug screen 



and it gives me a count of 0

however when i print it in the function right after self.placeIDArray.append(allPlace_ID) then all the elements are printed correctly as i want them. so that leaves me to suggest that the elements are not assigned outside of the function. if that is correct logic?

Comment: The elements should be assigned outside of the function. Are you calling `check()` inside the callback? Eg. `downloadRestaurantDetails { () -> () in self.check()}`?

Comment: I was calling check outside the callback but inside the viewDidLoad.

Comment: so self.placeIDArray.append(allPlace_ID) should be used elsewhere? where would I place it to populate the array? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: just attempted to call self.check() in the callback. but nothing happens? i call it outside the callback, and it gives me a count of 0... :(

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downloadRestaurantDetails` is asynchronous. So if you call `check` right after calling the above function, then it's possible (and very likely) that the JSON has not been fetched yet and so `placeIDArray` has not been filled yet. You must call it in the callback, because that's when the data has actually been downloaded and filled into the array.

So:

1. Add the callback after the data has been set:

   ```
   func downloadRestaurantDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
       //url is acquired through a file created for global variables
       Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
           if let value  = response.result.value {
               let json = JSON(value)

               //Acquire All place_id of restaurants
               if let results = json["results"].array {
                   for result in results {
                       if let allPlace_ID = result["place_id"].string {
                           //Add All place_id's into an array
                           self.placeIDArray.append(allPlace_ID)

                       }

                   }
                   // !!! Call the callback:
                   completed()
               }
   }
   ```
2. Then you can call `check` inside the callback:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       downloadRestaurantDetails { () -> () in
           // The array is now filled.
           self.check()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: genius! thank you so much! :) fun getting problems figured out!

Comment: i moved the completed() call to right before the 2nd to last closed curly  on the downloadRestaurantDetails function so it doesn't loop a bajillion times. but other than that it fixed my issue perfectly!